# Installing pow rack server from source on 32bit CPU

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, rack, rack-pow

Found out about [pow](http://pow.cx) just now and trying to install it on a laptop with a 32bit processor. I am running into (hopefully) a minor error.

During the [installation](https://github.com/37signals/pow/wiki/Installation) from source I get the following error:

```
*** Installing local configuration files...
mkdir: /Users/username/Library/Application Support: Permission denied


node.js:134
    throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
    ^
Error: Command failed: mkdir: /Users/username/Library/Application Support: Permission denied

at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:102:15)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:67:17)
at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:172:12)
at Socket.emit (events.js:64:17)
at Array.<anonymous> (net.js:837:12)
at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:126:26)
pow@0.3.2 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/pow 
├── log@1.2.0
├── async@0.1.8
├── coffee-script@1.1.2
├── nack@0.13.1 (netstring@0.2.0)
└── connect@1.7.1
```

I have tried to change the permissions on the application support folder using:

```
sudo chmod 777 ~/Library/Application\ Support/
```

and can verify the permissions using:

```
ls -la ~/Library/ | less
```

I get the following:

```
drwxrwxrwx+ 15 username  blah   510 26 Sep 19:16 Application Support
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction as I seem to have hit a brick wall thanks

Answer (score 0):

From completly unrelated [git issue](https://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues/194#issuecomment-369492):

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/
```

& then run install **without** sudo

```
npm -g install
```

Worked for me...